# Windows 10 thinks it's up to date, but it's not

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows 10 downloaded a big update not long ago and went through a lengthy upgrade process. Partway through the system locked up. The little progress spinner stopped spinning and it sat there for hours.

So I powered down, the system appeared to go through a recovery process, and then I checked for updates again. It says that "Your device is up to date", but the current version is 1511, build 10586.633. That version isn't current; version 1607 was released in August.

But whenever I check for updates, it says that the system is up to date.

Windows Update troubleshooter reports no problems.

How do I persuade Windows to install 1607?

Comment: Perhaps try to use "Secunia PSI" or try to download the most recent, Patchs, Fixes, Updates, Rollup or Upgrade from the Windows Website if avaiable. e.g. Windows Catalog

Comment: @GiaRui Secunia doesn't check for Windows updates itself, it relies on Windows update which in this case doesn't work.

Comment: Version 1607 is stilling being rolled out by Windows Update, if you want it today, use the ISO to upgrade.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k No, but I have a theory. I'm using grub to dual-boot Ubuntu. I think that may be the cause. My plan is to get rid of grub.

Comment: Possibly so.  The "Troubleshooting 101" philosophy tells us that we should consider all possibilities, but a dual-boot shouldn't stop Windows Update from working.  That being said, while I am certainly not a Linux guru I have heard good things about the Ubuntu distro.  However, we do see a lot of questions in the Super User community posted by people who encounter various challenges trying to maintain a Windows 10/Linux dual boot configuration.  Personally, I would be much more inclined to use the built-in Hyper-V capability in Windows 10 Pro and utilize a Ubuntu virtual machine, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I persuade Windows to install 1607?

In your situation, I would probably download Version 1607 myself and initiate the install manually from a USB drive or DVD disc:

[Download Windows 10 Disc Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/)

Comment: I got rid of the dual-boot. Trying to do the upgrade the normal way still didn't work, I downloaded a full version of Windows 10. That worked.

Comment: I am glad to hear that everything worked out well in the end.

Answer (score -1):

You can upgrade your PC using the Media Creation Tool from Microsoft. When it opens, select Upgrade and follow the installer. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).