# Remove Start Menu Labels (Win10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

Apologies if this is the wrong site to post on, I was told Superuser was where questions about Windows belonged. I'm trying to find a setting or some console command that will remove the labels from Start menu items. On my Win10 desktop, it defaulted to a labelless interface until you expand it, but on my laptop it defaulted to the opposite and I cannot find a setting to change this:

(Version 1607 OS Build 14393.693)

[image: win 10 start menu labels]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have installed? Open RUN and type "winver" and press Enter, then add the full Version and OS Build number(s) to your question.

Comment: You aren't running the latest version of Windows 10 on that machine. [Download version 1607 yourself to initiate the install manually](http://superuser.com/questions/1143349/windows-10-thinks-its-up-to-date-but-its-not/1143353), and once it's finished you will be all set.

Comment: @Run5k My computer is completely updated.

Comment: Please verify again that `winver` reports Version 1607. Windows Update finding nothing is not a valid check for that. /edit: Nevermind, missed the edit.

Comment: Your Windows installation may have become a hybrid of both pre-Upgrade and post-Upgrade components. I suggest you reinstall it. Just for fun, please provide the output of `Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost` (execute in Powershell).

Comment: This seems backwards.  What version and build of Windows 10 is your desktop running?

Answer (score -1):

Click the menu button at the top left of the start menu to hide or unhide labels in Windows 10.

[image]

Source: [CNET - How to customize the Windows 10 Start menu](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-customize-the-windows-10-start-menu/)

Comment: I'm aware this exists, but it is not a permanent solution.

Comment: @Aaron, as I implied within my original comment (above), this interface was changed when the last [major update to Windows 10 (version 1607) was released several months ago](http://www.windowscentral.com/whats-new-start-menu-windows-10-anniversary-update).  If you update your laptop, you will have your permanent solution.  If you `Check for updates` and it doesn't start the install, you can [download version 1607 yourself to initiate the install manually](https://superuser.com/questions/1143349/windows-10-thinks-its-up-to-date-but-its-not/1143353#1143353).