# Windows 10: upgrading to Creators Update from 1607 - link in Settings does nothing

Tags: windows-10-v1703

Currently on Windows 10 Enterprise, v1607:

[image]

It's apparently up to date, but the `Yes, show me how` link does nothing:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be?  I'd quite like to get it updated sooner rather than later.

---

Edit:

- Defer updates is not switched on
- Not on Current Branch for Business (or LTSB)
- Not a member of a domain (just the default workgroup called WORKGROUP)

It was originally a bare metal install from September 2015, standard retail version with an MSDN key.

Windows update never offered me 1607 either so I downloaded that and installed it manually.  Since then, Windows updates have appeared regularly.

Just seems weird that (unlike with 1607 which was never offered), Windows Update is mentioning the next upgrade, but clicking the link doesn't do anything.  I was expecting it to open a browser and take me to a download page.

Comment: Is "Defer updates/upgrades" turned on? Are you on Current Branch for Business?

Comment: More importantly, if you are running `Windows 10 Enterprise` is this machine actually on an Active Directory domain?  If so, your Domain Admin personnel are probably controlling when Version 1703 will be available to the Windows 10 workstations, and you will need to wait until the push it throughout the domain.  If not, you can follow the directions described within the `Possible Duplicate` question to use the Update Assistant or simply download the full OS image (for USB or an ISO to burn to DVD) and initiate the upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 thinks it's up to date, but it's not](https://superuser.com/questions/1143349/windows-10-thinks-its-up-to-date-but-its-not)

Comment: The link just goes to the Upgrade Assistant download page.  Just download it by hand.  Additionally like 1607 it's being slowly rolled out.  So it's not been pushed to you.  But the link is offering for you to do it yourself by using the upgrade assistant

Comment: *"Just seems weird that ... Windows Update is mentioning the next upgrade, but clicking the link doesn't do anything."*  On the other hand, it is also rather unusual to be running Windows 10 Enterprise on a machine that isn't a domain workstation, so it wouldn't be too surprising to find some quirks regarding the [Windows 10 Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10-creators-update-version-1703/1199780#1199780) under those circumstances. I would probably wait a bit longer and after 2 or 3 more Microsoft monthly patches, download & install it.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't worry about "[Yes, show me how](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=841849)" link. It is totally useless for the Enterprise edition. (See for yourself with the link I just gave.)

As for the update not appearing in Settings, there could be two reasons:

1. *You are updating from Microsoft Update channel:* This update is being pushed out in several phases. It is quite natural that you haven't got it yet. Don't worry. You'll get it eventually, hopefully before 11 May 2017.
2. *You are updating from Windows Server Update Services (WSUS):* Your domain administrator must explicitly select it in WSUS. It appears as a new product in Windows category.

You can also request a Windows 10 installation media that has Creators Update in it from your volume licensing channel. Only, I heard the media won't be available until May.

Comment: Yes; Enterprise 1703 will be released in May; Has to do with support cycles more than anything (and perhaps waiting to release a fractionally better product to Enterprise)